# Will bitcoin core have to re-sync the whole block chain if I replace my wallet?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, wallet-recovery

I have an old wallet from 2013. After backing up and replacing my current wallet with the new one, will it require the client to re-sync and re-download the whole blockchain? Last time it took about a week so I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not need to redownload the entire blockchain. It may need to rescan the blockchain, but that does not require downloading any of it and will not take as long.